# SuiteTalk TransactionSearchAdvanced returns duplicate records

Tags: netsuite

When I trying to make TransactionSearchAdvanced (SalesOrder search) it returns dublicate records with same values. BodyFieldsOnly is set to true. Whats wrong in my code. Code is below

```
    TransactionSearchAdvanced advanced = new TransactionSearchAdvanced();
    TransactionSearch search = new TransactionSearch();
    TransactionSearchBasic basic = new TransactionSearchBasic();
    TransactionSearchRow tsRow = new TransactionSearchRow();
    TransactionSearchRowBasic rowBasic = new TransactionSearchRowBasic();


    basic.setType(new SearchEnumMultiSelectField(new String[] { "_salesOrder" }, SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf));
    basic.setAccount(new SearchMultiSelectField(new RecordRef[] { new RecordRef(null, "54", null, null) }, SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf));
    basic.setRecordType(new SearchStringField(RecordType._salesOrder , SearchStringFieldOperator.is));      
    basic.setOtherRefNum(new SearchTextNumberField(null, null, SearchTextNumberFieldOperator.notEmpty));
    basic.setInternalIdNumber(new SearchLongField(lastProcessedPoSalesOrderInternalId, null, SearchLongFieldOperator.greaterThan));
    search.setBasic(basic);

    rowBasic.setOtherRefNum(new SearchColumnTextNumberField[]{new SearchColumnTextNumberField()});
    rowBasic.setInternalId(new SearchColumnSelectField[]{new SearchColumnSelectField()});
    tsRow.setBasic(rowBasic);

    advanced.setColumns(tsRow);     

    advanced.setCriteria(search);
    result = netsuiteService.searchBodyFields(advanced);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a filter for mainline = True. The code should be something like this

```
basic.setMainLine(new SearchBooleanField(null, null, SearchBoolenFieldOperator.false));
```

Comment: if I add setMainLine to true in criteria I receive success response with empty SearchRowList.

Comment: Problem resolved. Just add mainLine to true in criteria and replace account filter. Thanks a lot.